# The DataTables are not responsive and taking too long to load the data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, datatables

I have 1000 records and I am able to fetch them from database like in one second. But they are taking like 9s for rendering. It is maybe because of data tables or I am looping through each record to display. If I disable the data tables performance is better but still not good. Following is my code, could you give your suggestions. I am pretty sure it is slow because of rendering and scripting.

```
<div class="table-responsive">

   <table class="display" id="list" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Content.Code
            </th>
            <th> @Content.Name </th>
            <th>
                @Content.Location
            </th>
            <th>
                @Content.Date
            </th>
            <th> @Content.Remaining </th>

            <th>
                @Content.Status
            </th>

            <th>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>

                <td>
                    @item.Code
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Location
                </td>

                <td>
                    @item.Date 
                </td>
                <td>

                    @item.ReDays
                </td>

                <td>
                    @item.Status
                </td>


                <td width="15%">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", new { id = item.Id })" class="btn btn-primary"> <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

                    @if (User.IsInRole("Admin") || ViewBag.HavePermission == true)
                    {
                       <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", new { id = item.Id })" class="btn btn-danger"> <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I don't want to use server-side processing because I don't know how to control this `HavePermisson` and `UserRole` part. Please, give a suggestion?

Comment: A user cannot possibly absorb 1000 record in one page. Use paging to display only (say) 20-50 records at a time

Comment: I mean I am showing 10 records per page but the page is unresponsive until it loads all the records into DataTable.

Comment: Because you are not using server side paging

Comment: I don't know how to control the permission part in Ajax. If you can give the answer, I can go for Server Side Processing.

Comment: To render the action links via ajax, have a collection of pre-rendered actions links in the ViewModels of the lines (the result of `Url.Action` are just strings, generate them in the ViewModel or Controller).